# transform multiple columns to records in Bigquery

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, bigdata

I'm trying to convert a flat table into a nested table in Bigquery.
If I want to take a row, and transform some of the columns into 2 fields:

1. key.name
2. key.value

for example, If I'm taking this table:
[image: chicago_crime table (BQ)]

and I want to convert it to the following structure:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can define this as an array. I would suggest putting this into a string struct so you have only one array:

```
select unique_key, cast_number, date,
       [struct('block' as key, block as value),
        struct('iucr' as key, iucr as value),
        struct('primary_type' as key, primary_type as value),
        . . .
       ] as key_values
```

But for what you specifically ask for:

```
select unique_key, cast_number, date,
       ['block', 'iucr', 'primary_type', . . . ] as keys,
       [block, iucr, primary_type, . . . ] as values
```

Note that these assume that the values are all strings.  You may have to convert some values if they are not.

Comment: Perfect! this is what I looking for. Thanks!

Comment: how to deal with "Array cannot have a null element; error in writing field values"?

Comment: @LHA . . . I think the error is pretty clear.  You need to either remove that column or give it a different value using `coalesce()`.